# Reduce database hits for Django podcast app

Tags: django

I'm building a podcast directory where episodes can be categorized. The code to generate a page for the podcast, a list of episodes, and a list of categories within each episode.

A podcast can have a "Sports" and "News" category. And one episode might have "Sports", while another might have "Sports" and "News" as categories.

The problem: I'm battering the database with looping within loops.  I know there's a way more efficient way.

Here's generally how the models are connected:

```
class Podcast(models.Model):
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Episode(models.Model):
    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    ...
```

Then, when I load the podcast page and want to put a list of categories and episodes within it:

```
class Podcast(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def get_categories(self):
        return self.category_set.all()

    @property
    def episodes_by_category(self):
        episodes_by_category = []
        for category in self.get_categories:
            episodes = self.episode_set.all().filter(categories=category)
            episodes_by_category.append({
                'category': category,
                'episodes': episodes,
                'count': len(episodes),
            })

        sorted_episodes_by_category = sorted(episodes_by_category, key = lambda i: i['count'],reverse=True)
        return sorted_episodes_by_category
```

Then, when I load an episode page, I show other episodes that share the same categories:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    ...

    @property
    def get_categories(self):
        return self.categories.all().prefetch_related('episode_set').select_related('podcast')

    @property
    def related_episodes_by_category(self):
        episodes_by_category = []
        for category in self.get_categories:
            episodes = category.episode_set.all().select_related('podcast')
            episodes_by_category.append({
                'category': category,
                'episodes': episodes,
                'count': len(episodes),
            })
        sorted_episodes_by_category = sorted(episodes_by_category, key = lambda i: i['count'],reverse=True)
        return sorted_episodes_by_category
```

Here's how I use it in a template on an podcast page:

```
{% for episode_batch in podcast.episodes_by_category %}
    <div class="sidebar-object mb-2 pb-2" id="categories">
        <div class="section-title section-title--style-1 mb-0">
            <h3 class="section-title-inner heading-sm strong-600 text-uppercase">
                Top <a href="{{episode_batch.category.get_absolute_url_cached|check_custom_domain:request}}" class="link">{{episode_batch.category.name|title}}</a> Episodes
            </h3>
        </div>

        <ul class="categories list-border--dotted">
            {% for episode in episode_batch.episodes %}
                {% if forloop.counter < 3 %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{episode.get_absolute_url_cached|check_custom_domain:request}}">{{episode.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here's how I use it in a template on an episode page:

```
{% for episode_batch in episode.related_episodes_by_category %}
    {% if episode_batch.category in episode_categories %}

        <div class="sidebar-object mb-2 pb-2" id="categories">
            <div class="section-title section-title--style-1 mb-0">
                <h3 class="section-title-inner heading-sm strong-600 text-uppercase">
                    Top <a href="{{episode_batch.category.get_absolute_url_cached|check_custom_domain:request}}" class="link">{{episode_batch.category.name|title}}</a> Episodes
                </h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="categories list-border--dotted">
                {% for episode in episode_batch.episodes %}
                    {% if forloop.counter < 3 %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{episode.get_absolute_url_cached|check_custom_domain:request}}">{{episode.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I realize I can reduce database load with caching, but before I do that, I'd love to optimize the way I'm fetching this information. Currently, I'm hitting the database 70-100 times per page load for a podcast with 10ish categories.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of how your accessing it in your view?

Comment: @RBowen Just added how I'm using in templates. In the class based view, i just load episode or podcast.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate your `Category` model and store categories as an array of string tags in a field in your `Episode` model. (You don't mention what database engine you use, but Postgres supports an array type.)

1. Query using `Episode.objects.filter(categories=[category])` *<-- note array notation*
2. Render using `{% for category in episode.categories %}`

Although Apple maintains a list of categories, podcast feeds are free to publish whatever they like, e.g. "Sports", "News", "Sports News", "Sporting News" as tags; if you haven't obsessively cleaned your data, your join keys will be a mess. Since in practice categories behave more like attributes than dimensions, there's no need to keep them in a separate table:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Episode(models.Model):
    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255))
    ...
```

This assumes you aren't doing anything more complicated in your `Category` model than storing the category name and an attribute or two. Typical candidates for normalization include entities like Podcast and Episode that have several descriptive attributes, but overall, normalizing on Category strikes me as far more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

There's a balance between a rewrite and making some smaller optimizations

In the below I've made some small changes to the episode model properties / template as an example. You could go further but this leaves the episode_batch intact

Model:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class Episode(models.Model):
    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True)
    ...

    @property
    def get_categories(self):
        #add an annotation to the get categories so you hit the database once for all counts
        categories = self.categories.annotate(episode_count=Count('episode')).prefetch_related('episode_set')
        return categories

    @property
    def related_episodes_by_category(self):
        episodes_by_category = []
        for category in self.get_categories:
            episodes = category.episode_set.all()

            #slice the episode queryset instead of using counter in the template
            episodes_by_category.append({
                'category': category,
                'episodes': episodes[0:2],
                'count': category.episode_count,
            })
        sorted_episodes_by_category = sorted(episodes_by_category, key = lambda i: i['count'],reverse=True)
        return sorted_episodes_by_category
```

Template:

```
{% for episode_batch in episode.related_episodes_by_category %}

        <div class="sidebar-object mb-2 pb-2" id="categories">
            <div class="section-title section-title--style-1 mb-0">
                <h3 class="section-title-inner heading-sm strong-600 text-uppercase">
                    Top <a href="{{episode_batch.category.get_absolute_url_cached|check_custom_domain:request}}" class="link">{{episode_batch.category.name|title}}</a> Episodes
                </h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="categories list-border--dotted">
                {% for episode in episode_batch.episodes %}

                        <li>
                            <a href="{{episode.get_absolute_url_cached|check_custom_domain:request}}">{{episode.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Notes:

removed the below line, I don't see where "episode_categories" is defined but if you do need to limit further move this to the view / property

```
{% if episode_batch.category in episode_categories %}
```

removed the below

```
{% if forloop.counter < 3 %}
```